# Automatically add UUID relation on prisma create

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I have a `User`, `UserProfile` and `Post` model in my Postgres database. The `User` and `UserProfile` depend on each other. I am trying to create a `User` that automatically creates a `UserProfile` with it, but I can't seem to find out how to automatically assume the `User`'s ID for the `UserProfile` relation, I am using UUID for the `User` model.

**Schema Models**

```js
model User {
  id             String       @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt      DateTime     @default(now())
  username       String       @unique @db.VarChar(20)
  emailEncrypted String       @unique
  emailIv        String       @unique
  password       String
  isMod          Boolean      @default(false)
  isAdmin        Boolean      @default(false)
  emailConfirmed Boolean      @default(false)
  profile        UserProfile?
}

model UserProfile {
  user     User      @relation(fields: [id], references: [id])
  id       String    @unique
  posts    Post[]
  comments Comment[]
}

model Post {
  id        String      @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt DateTime    @default(now())
  title     String      @db.VarChar(300)
  caption   String      @db.VarChar(1000)
  upvotes   Int         @default(0)
  downvotes Int         @default(0)
  comments  Comment[]
  author    UserProfile @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  String
}
```

**Query**

```js
const user = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
        username,
        emailEncrypted: encrypted,
        emailIv: iv,
        password: hashedPassword,
        profile: {
            create: {}, // create a UserProfile that assumes the created user's UUID as a relation
        },
    },
    select: {
        id: true,
    },
});
```

As you can see, I have tried to use `create: {}` in order to assume the user's UUID, but it fails to create an actual `UserProfile`, just a `User`, which of course breaks the system.

Answer (score 4):

I ran this as well. In order to include `profile` data after creating the user I did the following tweak.

```js
const user = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
        username: "username",
        emailEncrypted: "encrypted",
        emailIv: "iv",
        password: "hashedPassword",
        profile: {
            create: {},
        },
    },
    select: {
        id: true,
        createdAt: true,
        emailConfirmed: true,
        emailIv: true,
        emailEncrypted: true,
        isAdmin: true,
        isMod: true,
        password: true,
        profile: true,
        username: true,
    },
});
```

This outputs,

[image]

No issue it worked fine.

Still wondering what the issue you faced was.

Can you paste the error log ?.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way of adding relations in Prisma. You use `create` to add a relation and the UUID will automatically be added to that record. You do not need to do anything else. I tried the following and works fine for me:

[image: Entry added]

[image: Resulting record is created]

Comment: Thanks, Prisma doesn't create a `UserProfile` automatically however, because the `UserProfile` is optional, how can I fix this?

Comment: If you pass `profile: { create: { // required fields }` in the object then Prisma will automatically create the UserProfile.

Comment: Thanks, already tried this, but I get a `PANIC` error when trying to get the `UserProfile`s.

Comment: What's the error? Also is your `@prisma/client` and `prisma` on the latest version?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Prisma. I am now getitng a null constraint violation error when creating the post along with the user. I could create a user profile separately to the user, but that wouldn't be the best way to do it.